# Python pandas grouping for correlation analysis

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

Assume two dataframes, each with a datetime index, and each with one column of unnamed data.  The dataframes are of different lengths and the datetime indexes may or may not overlap.

df1 is length 20.  df2 is length 400.  The data column consists of random floats.

I want to iterate through df2 taking 20 units per iteration, with each iteration incrementing the start vector by one unit - and similarly the end vector by one unit.  On each iteration I want to calculate the correlation between the 20 units of df1 and the 20 units I've selected for this iteration of df2.  This correlation coefficient and other statistics will then be recorded.

Once the loop is complete I want to plot df1 with the 20-unit vector of df2 that satisfies my statistical search - thus needing to keep up with some level of indexing to reacquire the vector once analysis has been completed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more specifics of the questions such as, why are you doing this or do dates matter, this will do what you asked. I'm happy to update based on your feedback.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[random.randint(0, 20) for x in range(20)]}, index = pd.date_range(start = '2013-01-01',periods = 20, freq = 'D'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[random.randint(0, 20) for x in range(400)]}, index = pd.date_range(start = '2013-01-10',periods = 400, freq = 'D'))

corr = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,380):

    t0 = df1.reset_index()['a'] # grab the numbers from df1
    t1 = df2.iloc[i:i+20].reset_index()['b'] # grab 20 days, incrementing by one each time
    t2 = df2.iloc[i:i+20].index[0] # set the index to be the first day of df2

    corr = corr.append(pd.DataFrame({'corr':t0.corr(t1)}, index = [t2])) #calculate the correlation and append it to the DF

# plot it and save the graph
corr.plot()
plt.title("Correlation Graph")
plt.ylabel("(%)")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('corr.png')
```